# What determines the property of vacuum that allows EM field to propagate?

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, vacuum

As in case of sound it the disturbance that propagates by exchange of energy between particles. what is analogously related to em wave, where there is propagation of energy stored in electric and magnetic field?
what is the property of vaccum in this case?

Answer (score 3):

the two properties of the vacuum responsible for this are called the *permittivity* of free space and the *permeability* of free space. Maxwell's equations contain these constants and from them the propagation speed of electromagnetic radiation can be derived.

Comment: thanks but what determines that permitivity and permeability of vaccum. suppose in case of rubberband that constant is determined by the propety of itself. how the molecules in it  interact.

Comment: those constants are built into the structure of the vacuum. if they didn't exist, neither would we.

Comment: thanksto previous comment,but what you mean by built into structure of vaccum

Comment: like what is the structure of vaccum?

Comment: try a search on the "classical vacuum" for more information